# What is $r-n+1$ equal to?

Tags: factorial

So I am working on factorials and can easily show that
$$r = \frac{r!}{(r-1)!}$$

By expanding the factorial $$r! = r(r-1)\cdots(r-n+1)$$
Then dividing both sides by $(r-1) \cdots (r-n+1)=(r-1)!$

However, I cannot figure out the equivalent for
$$r-n+1 = \frac{r!}{r(r-1) \cdots(r-n)}$$

Comment: Your last "equation" is false, in general.

Comment: Did you mean $(r-n+1)!=\frac{r!}{r(r-1)\cdots(r-n)}$?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I take it that its not supposed to equal to $r-n+1$ because we cannot get it so cleanly like $r$? What does the $r(r-1) \cdots (r-n)$ equate to in factorial notation then?

Comment: Are you trying to derive $\binom{r}{n}$?

Comment: "What does the  $r(r-1) \cdots (r-n)$ equate to in factorial notation then?" To investigate this, do some special cases until you see a pattern.  For example $7\cdot6\cdot5\cdot4 = $ ?? in  factorial notation.

Comment: Note $r!= r(r-1) ...... (r-n)(r-n-1)......2\cdot 1$ so $\frac {r!}{r(r-1).....(r-n)} = (r-n-1)....2\cdot 1 = (r-n-1)! = (r-(n+1))!$.  Now what actually are you trying to figure out? What you have written is certainly not true.

Comment: "What does the r(r−1)⋯(r−n) equate to in factorial notation then"  Well as  $r! = r(r-1)......3\cdot 2\cdot 1= [r(r-1).....(r-n)]\times [(r-n-1)..........\cdot 2\cdot 1$ then $r(r-1)...(r-n) = \frac {r!}{ [(r-n-1)..........\cdot 2\cdot 1} = \frac {r!}{(r-n-1)!}$.  Now it's usefulr to think of $r -n-1 = r - something$ so what is $something$?  That something is $n+ 1$ so $r-n-1 = r-(n+1)!$ and $\frac {r!}{(r-(n+1)!} = r(r-1)....(r-n)$.  I think that is what you are getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I get what you are asking!

You are asking what does $r(r-1)\cdots(r-n+1)$ equal in a simple factorial equation.

Well. $r!$ is $r$ multiplied by everything down to $1$.  But $r(r-1)\cdots(r-n+1)$ is $r$ multiplied only down to $r-n+1$.  Everything else $r-n$ down to $1$ is missing.  If we multiplied by $(r-n).......2\cdot 1$ we'd get.

$r! = [r(r-1)\cdots(r-n+1)]\times [(r-n)...... 2\cdot 1]$.

Note: $[(r-n)...... 2\cdot 1] = (r-n)!$ so if we divide both sides by that we get:

$\frac {r!}{(r-n)!} = [r(r-1)\cdots(r-n+1)]$

This is useful as shorthand to think whenever you see $\frac {r!}{(r-n)!}$ that that means $r(r-1).........(r-n+1)$.

This way if anyone ask you "If you have $52$ cards and you deal out $17$ of them then how many different sequence of $17$ cards can you have" you can say "Well there are $52$ choices for the first dealt card and $51$ choices for the second all the way down to $36$ choices for the $17$th card so that is $52\cdot 51\cdot .... \cdot 36 = \frac {52!}{35!}$".  Now you can know you can just take a shortcut... There are $\frac {52!}{(52-17)!}$ ways to do it.

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you for sharing. I hadn't realised that we count the factorial all the way back to 1, I think this is what I was missing which explains why I had $r-n+1$